# Where can I find the railroad diagrams for drools documentation in a larger size

Tags: jboss, documentation, drools

I'm trying to read the railroad diagrams in the drools documentation. I'm specifically looking at [section 6.8.3.9](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.20.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_railroad_diagrams) and the size of the images is so small that I am unable to read the text and diagram notations clearly.

Where can I find these same images in a larger size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the name of the image file in the documentation (which is a png file) and then find the svg counterpart of it here: https://github.com/kiegroup/kie-docs/tree/master/_images/LanguageReference

For example, the svg counterpart of the [AccumulateAction.png](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.20.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/LanguageReference/AccumulateAction.png) image is this one: https://github.com/kiegroup/kie-docs/blob/master/_images/LanguageReference/AccumulateAction.svg

Hope it helps,

Comment: oh yes.. very helpful.